# How to Add Multiple Meta Tags For Different Post Separately in Blogger?

Tags: tags, metadata, blogs, blogger, content-type

```
<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == "PAGE-URL"'>
<meta content='PAGE-DESCRIPTION' name='description'/>
<meta content='PAGE-KEYWORDS' name='keywords'/>
</b:if>
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == "PAGE-URL"'>
<meta content='PAGE-DESCRIPTION' name='description'/>
<meta content='PAGE-KEYWORDS' name='keywords'/>
</b:if>
</b:include>
```

This code gives me error says that we should not put "Unknown runtime binding: else in widget"

Comment: So how to Add Multiple Meta tags in "all-head-content"

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with `b:else` statement in the above code. When using the `b:else` statement, the `b:if` statement doesn't need to explicitly closed & opened. I would instead suggest that use `b:elseif` operator provided by Blogger. A working code would look like -

```
<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.url == "PAGE-URL"'>
    <meta content='PAGE-DESCRIPTION' name='description'/>
    <meta content='PAGE-KEYWORDS' name='keywords'/>
  <b:elseif cond='data:blog.url == "PAGE-URL"' />
    <meta content='PAGE-DESCRIPTIONsss' name='description'/>
    <meta content='PAGE-KEYWORDSssss' name='keywords'/>
  </b:if>
</b:include>
```

Comment: it gives me same error "Unknown runtime binding: elseif in widget"

Comment: @SagarMistry Make sure to copy the whole code from the above example. In your code, there is also an issue with `b:include` tag being wrongly closed

Comment: yes i copied whole code and paste in <b:include></b:include>

Comment: I tested the code at my side, its working without problem. Here is screenshot showing the same - http://i.imgur.com/7IbDeDA.gif